# How to make a class use different implementations of injected dependencies?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ninject

Imagine I have this classes:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly ISomething1 _something1;
    private readonly ISomething2 _something2;

    public MyClass(ISomething1 something1, ISomething2 something2)
    {
        _something1 = something1;
        _something2 = something2;
    }

    public SomeObject Get(AnotherObject anotherObject)
    {
        var a = _something1.Calculate(anotherObject.Property1);
        var b = _something2.Get(anotherObject.Property2, a);

        return b;
    }
}

public class MyClass2 : IMyClass
{
    private readonly ISomething1 _something1;
    private readonly ISomething2 _something2;

    public MyClass(ISomething1 something1, ISomething2 something2)
    {
        _something1 = something1;
        _something2 = something2;
    }

    public SomeObject Get(AnotherObject anotherObject)
    {
        var a = _something1.Calculate(anotherObject.Property1);
        var b = _something2.Get(anotherObject.Property2, a);

        return b;
    }
}
```

It looks like `MyClass` and `Myclass2` are the same. However, the difference is that I am injecting different implementations of `ISomething1` and `ISomething2` for these classes using `Ninject`:

```
//MyClass
Bind<ISomething1>().To<AmazingSomething>().WhenInjectedInto<MyClass>();
Bind<ISomething2>().To<BeautifulSomething>().WhenInjectedInto<MyClass>();

//MyClass2
Bind<ISomething1>().To<GoodSomething>().WhenInjectedInto<MyClass2>();
Bind<ISomething2>().To<UglySomething>().WhenInjectedInto<MyClass2>();
```

I don't like this solution because it violates DRY principle. However, I like it because it is following Open/closed principle (I hope so).

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: It looks like a code smell for me, because as you said the classes are the same. They are only different on runtime.  Without any information about the lifecycle of the MyClass1/2 objects, a guess is to use a factory pattern.

Comment: @rboe you mean using a factory for `ISomething1` and `ISomething2` inside `MyClass`?

Comment: @rboe something like `_something1Factory.Get(someType).Calculate(anotherObject.Property1)` ?

Comment: Not inside ´MyClass´. ´MyClass1´ and ´MyClass2´ will be combined to ´MyClass´ (perhaps the IMyClass interface is not needed anymore) and there is a Factory (or multiple) that creates ´IMyClass´ instances.

Comment: @rboe which instances a Factory will create? You said that there will be only one instance - `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you don't need `MyClass2`.

Most likely you need factory to create `IMyClass` implementations, using some custom logic to choose, what `ISomething1` and `ISomething2` implementations to inject.

I'm not using Ninject in my projects, but I believe, that you could attach some metadata to your dependencies, and this will help you to implement selection logic.

E.g., using poor man's DI there will be something like this:

```
public class MyClassFactory
{
    public IMyClass Create()
    {
        if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            return new MyClass(new ASomething1(), new ASomething2());
        }

        return new MyClass(new BSomething1(), new BSomething2());
    }
}
```

So, factory code depends on how all these objects must be instantiated and combined.

Comment: Thank you. I have found how it's done in Ninject - https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface:-Referencing-Named-Bindings#using-whenanyancestornamedlikefactorymethod-to-define-conditional-bindings-on-factory-methods.